# Al compilar para Angularjs4, la pagina se mantiene en "Loading... " con "ng build --prod"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy aprendiendo Angularjs4, mientras estoy probando código todo va bien, es decir ejecutando

> ng serve

El problema se presenta cuando intento compilar el proyecto para producción, la sentencia que ejecuto es la siguiente

> ng build --prod

entiendo que esa sentencia debe producir el código compilado de angular en la carpeta "dist" del proyecto, y en efecto la carpeta se crea y se llena de distintos archivos, entre los cuales esta un index.html, pero cuando entro en esa carpeta a través de localhost, la pantalla se queda con el mensaje

> Loading...

pareciera que el código no esta enlazando con el framework.

Comment: Ricardo, buenas, en la consola no te aparece ningún error?

Comment: No, pero es un problema de rutas, ya lo resolví, las rutas de las etiquetas de script aparecen sin "./" al inicio, después que se ejecuta "ng build --prod" para compilar, hay que colocar "./" al inicio de cada una de las rutas después de compilar, en el archivo "index.html" del directorio "dist"

Comment: cierra la pregunta si la resolviste pls

Comment: @AlejandroLora nose como cerrar la pregunta

Comment: Puedes hacer dos cosas, borrarla, o responderte a ti mismo explicando detalladamente por si alguien le pasa igual, a las 24 horas mas tardes podrás marcarla como resuelta y obtendras los puntos. Asi se quedaria cerrada @RicardoGabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema lo resolví añadiendo "./" al inicio de cada una de las rutas generadas en el archivo "index.html" de la carpeta "dist" después de ejecutar el comando

> ng build --prod

Acá les dejo el archivo "index.html" ya modificado, repito, solo coloque "./" al inicio de cada ruta

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NuevoProyecto</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./inline.bundle.js">
   </script><script type="text/javascript" src="./polyfills.bundle.js">
   </script><script type="text/javascript" src="./styles.bundle.js">
   </script><script type="text/javascript" src="./vendor.bundle.js">
   </script><script type="text/javascript" src="./main.bundle.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: En Angular 15 –prod está en desuso desde Angular 12 y se eliminó en Angular 14 en función de estas API y características obsoletas de Angular .

Use  ```--configuration production``` en su lugar.

Entonces el comando será ```ng build --configuration production```

más información https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularcli